# how can I block google adsense from loading in android webview?

Tags: android, webview

how can I block google adsense from loading in android webview?

I want to block the ads.

Answer (score 0):

Do we really need to block adsense from displaying in webview? Please refer to this:
http://masimfarooq.wordpress.com/2012/09/07/how-to-add-google-adsense-ads-to-your-android-app/
I do aware that the policy of adsense for mobile states that:
The use of AdSense for mobile in a mobile application is a violation of AdSense policies. A mobile application constitutes any downloadable application, even if a WebView is used to display the ad.
https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/68724?hl=en

However, we are not using adsense for mobile. Mostly we use adsense for content with ad size 320x50 (mobile banner).